# Add hyperlink to Outlook email which goes to row number when opening Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel spreadsheet which sends email using VBA:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "This is email text, click the link <a href='C:\test.xlsm & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Address'></a>"

On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = "####"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Sales Tracker: A New Task has been added to the tracker"
    .HTMLBody = strbody & strbody2 & strbody3 & strbody4
    .Send 'displays outlook email
    'Application.SendKeys "%s" 'presses send as a send key
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

The email is sent when a user clicks on a specific cell within the active row.

I include the Excel spreadsheet in the email with a hyperlink.

Now I want to **add to the hyperlink to include the cell reference of the row the user clicks on**.

The idea is the hyperlink when clicked will open the spreadsheet and will take the user to the row the link refers to and highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the reference of the sheet in your link (even though I'm not sure that this will be enough), so try something like this :

```
href='[C:\test.xlsm]" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Address & "'></a>"
```

to match this format :

```
href='[C:\test.xlsm]SheetName!A1'
```

And more importantly, you forgot to close the quotation marks properly, so here it goes :

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "This is email text, click the link <a href='[C:\test.xlsm]" & _
            ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row).Address & "'></a>"

On Error Resume Next


With OutMail
    .To = "####"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Sales Tracker: A New Task has been added to the tracker"
    .HTMLBody = strbody & strbody2 & strbody3 & strbody4
    .Send 'displays outlook email
    'Application.SendKeys "%s" 'presses send as a send key
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with hyperlink, most likely not. Only thing that comes to my mind is to add Worksheet_Activate() event to spreadsheet you are attaching, and there point to range you wish, but not with hyperlink.